# Change the text of a Span

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the text of a span upon button click.

Some other questions solve this by appending text but I don't want to keep the original text and rather substitute it completely.

My code looks like this now:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="msgbtn">Messages <span id="mgsunread" class="badge badge-light">4</span></button>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('#msgbtn').on('click', function(event) {
 span = document.getElementById("mgsunread");
 txt = document.createTextNode("6");
 span.appendChild(txt);
});
```

I would be grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, that would be simply

```
$('#msgbtn').on('click', function(event) {
  $("#mgsunread").text("6");
});
```

If you still want to stick to vanila javascript

```
document.getElementById("mgsunread").textContent="6";
```

Comment: Thanks sp far, but I've read that if I do that I somehow make myself vulnerable to an XSS attack.

Answer (score 0):

Pure js approach.

```js
document.getElementById('msgbtn').onclick = replaceText;

function replaceText() {
document.getElementById('mgsunread').innerHTML = 'hello world'
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="msgbtn">Messages <span id="mgsunread" class="badge badge-light">4</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you replace lines 3 and 4 with `span.innerText = “6”;`

This sets the text inside of your span tag to 6.